# Bind dropdownlist from jquery ajax call success function using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax

jquery ajax returning json from server and trying to bind the returned json into dropdown list using angularjs.

my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "gets",
datatype: "json",
async: true,
data: 
{
'spj': JSON.stringify(spjson),                
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
},
success: function (json)
{
var jsonList = json;
}
});
```

dropdownlist in html:

```
<html>
<select ng-model='selvalue' ng-options='val.category for val in vals'> 
</select>
</html>
```

Angular controler:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('ddtest', ['ui.utils']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) 
{
$scope.vals = jsonList 
}
</script>
```

please suggest how to bind the dropdownlist from jquery ajax call using angularjs.

Comment: why don't you use $http service? That is the angular way

Comment: yes it is working through $http but my requirement is using jquery ajax service.

Comment: I can't see the $http service used... why is there that requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, why not use angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)?

If you really want to do this, your ajax call will need to live inside your controller (which itself is not a good practice), and inside your call...

```
success: function (json) {
  $scope.vals = json;
  $scope.$apply(); //you will need to apply because angular does not do digest update here
}
```

But as I mentioned, ideally you would create a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to hold your $http call or $resource.

Comment: Dear NenadP, it is working well. the reason y i wanted is, i want to test the performance with 1000 uniqe skills. thanks lot.

Comment: Ah, ok then - glad to help :)